# An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: ArgumentCountError Message: Too few arguments to function User::pengembalian_buku()

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to make a book return. but when moving to the book return page. displays an error...

> Controller

public function pengembalian_buku($id){

```
    if ($this->session->userdata('email') === NULL) {
        redirect('auth');
    }

    $data = $this->BookModel->getDataById_Pm($id);

    $pengembalian = array (
        'id_pinjaman'          => $data['id_pinjaman'],
        'tanggal'              => date('Y-m-d'),
        'no_pinjaman'          => $data['no_pinjaman'],
        'nama_anggota'         => $data['nama_anggota'],
        'kategori_buku'        => $data['kategori_buku'],

    );

    $kembali = $this->db->insert('pengembalian_buku', $pengembalian);
    //mengecek apakah 
    if ($kembali = true) {
        $delete = $this->BookModel->deletePm($id);
        if ($delete = true) {
           
            redirect('/user/pengembalian_buku', $id, $kembali, $delete);

        }
    }
    
}
```

> Model

public function getDataById_Pm($id){

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('peminjaman_buku');
    $this->db->where('peminjaman_buku.id_pinjaman', $id);
    return $this->db->get()->row_array();
              
}
public function deletePm($id){
    $this->db->where('id_pinjaman', $id);
    $this->db->delete('peminjaman_buku'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$kembali = $this->db->insert('pengembalian_buku', $pengembalian);
    //mengecek apakah 
    if ($kembali == true) {
        $delete = $this->BookModel->deletePm($id);
        if ($delete == true) {
            redirect('/user/pengembalian_buku/'.$id);
        }
    }
```

$kembali and $delete will return Boolean value (true /  false). So you need to use Comparison oprator "==" not "="

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the wrong language.

Saya juga indo mas.

But here it is.

```
    if ($this->session->userdata('email') === NULL) {
        redirect('auth');
    }

    $data = $this->BookModel->getDataById_Pm($id);

    $pengembalian = array (
        'id_pinjaman'          => $data['id_pinjaman'],
        'tanggal'              => date('Y-m-d'),
        'no_pinjaman'          => $data['no_pinjaman'],
        'nama_anggota'         => $data['nama_anggota'],
        'kategori_buku'        => $data['kategori_buku'],

    );

    $this->db->trans_start();
    $this->db->insert('pengembalian_buku', $pengembalian);
    $kembali = $this->db->insert_id();
    $this->db->trans_complete();
    
    if ($kembali = > 0)
    {
        //Success//
    } else {
        //Failed//
    }

}
```